# How do I ensure that website (a react webapp) can only be accessed as a redirection from another website, and not directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, redirect, authentication

I am running a SAAS company that is websited at [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com), and I have a business-partner that is websited at [www.mypartner.com](http://www.mypartner.com). I'd like to redirect a user which is logged-in to [www.mypartner.com](http://www.mypartner.com) portal to [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) without requiring the user to login again.

I understand that oAuth 2.0 is the right solution to this problem. I am wondering, however, if there are any lighter alternatives, since customer doesnt use oAuth (they have a simple postgres table with uname/passwords, and an old php based website).

So far, this is a solution I have come up with:

1. The user is logged-in into [www.mypartner.com](http://www.mypartner.com), and hence, we have the user's details like their name, email-address, customer no. etc
2. We can ask [www.mypartner.com](http://www.mypartner.com) developers to redirect the user to our website at [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com), while putting the user details in the header. Since both websites are https, an eavesdropper cannot get these values
3. [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) can then create / retrieve the user that matches the passed info, pre-fill the form etc and carry on the business

Are there any major drawbacks in this solution?

One concern I have is that anyone can put these fields into the header and *log-in* to [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com). To avoid this, is it possible to ensure the following:

1. No one can access [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) unless they are being redirected from [www.mypartner.com](http://www.mypartner.com) ?

Comment: Yes, with oAuth.

Comment: Please consider using RC2606-compliant TLDs or [example second level domain names](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606#section-3). Using other URLs can confuse people or send them to malware-infected domains. Note that `mypartner.com` is a squatter domain, where malware can commonly reside.